# How to do a horizontal index match with multiple values

Tags: excel, indexing, match, multiple-value

I'm having trouble getting this formula to run. I need to return multiple values horizontally for work.

I've tried a few formulas online however this seems to be the simplest .

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$142,SMALL(IF($A$2=$I$2:$I$142,ROW($I$2:$I$142)-MIN(ROW($I$2:$I$142))+1,""),COLUMN(J2)))
```

All I'm getting is #VALUE!. I'm not quite sure how to use the column function, I feel like this may be my issue. For reference I'm entering this formula into J2 and hoping for results horizontally from there.

Comment: change `COLUMN(J2)` to `COLUMN(A1)`

Comment: snd since the array part is the Small you can shorten the formula to `=INDEX($H:$H,SMALL(IF($A$2=$I$2:$I$142,ROW($I$2:$I$142)),COLUMN(A1)))`